# Static method in java

Tags: java, static

I heard that static methods should use only static variables in java.
But, main method is also static, right?

Comment: Yes, `main` methods are `static` - what's your question?

Comment: we may r may not use static variables in main. i just want to make it confirm whether the statement "static methods should use only static variables". if its correct, how can v use non stativ variables in main??

Comment: If you try creating a normal variable in the Main class. You can't access it in the static void main function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your question: is the statement " static methods should use only static variables" correct?

No. The statement is not correct.

The correct statement will be "static methods can only use those instance variables that are defined static"

Take a look at following code and read the comments:

```
Class A{
    int i;
    static int j;

    public static void methodA(){
        i = 5; //cannot use since i is not static
        j = 2; //can use.

        int k = 3; //k is local variable and can be used no problem

        **EDIT:**//if you want to access i
        A a = new A();
        //A.i = 5; //can use.  
        a.i = 5; // it should be non-capital "a" right?
    }
}
```

Comment: I modified to answer to include "how to access non-static instance vars in static method"

Comment: "instance variables defined static" is incorrect. If they're defined static, the variables are named as class variables(static variables) NOT instance variables. static methods access class variables directly and can access instance variables through instance handler.

Comment: @Yergalem is right, there's officially no such thing as "instance variables defined static", "A field that is not declared static (sometimes called a non-static field) is called an instance variable. " https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1

Comment: So say 2 users are accessing this class at the same time - and rather than 5, a random number is put in a.i - will both users see the same random number or a different one?

Answer (score 18):

First of all, a technicality: it's *NOT* true that "`main` method is also static". You can define a non-static `main` method, with whatever signature you choose; it just won't be a valid Java application entry point.

With regards to "static methods should use only static variables", this is also *NOT* true. The key concept here is that static methods and fields are class-specific, not instance-specific. You simply can't access an instance variable/method if you don't actually have an instance of that class; it's a compilation error.

So to be precise, without an instance, you can't access instance fields/methods. You can access static fields/methods without an instance. If you need to access instance fields/methods from a static method, you have to get an instance of that class one way or another, either by simply instantiating it, or by getting a reference to it from a static field or method parameter.

Let's take a look at this simple example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  System.out.println(args.length);
}
```

`length` is *NOT* a static field; it's an instance field of array instances, which `args` is. The static method `main` is able to get this instance (and thus access its instance methods and fields) because it's passed in as an argument.

Also, `println` is *NOT* a static method; it's an instance method of `PrintStream` instances. The static method `main` is able to get this instance by accessing the static field `out` of the class `System`.

---

To summarize:

- A Java application entry point is a method that:

  - is named `main`
  - is `public` and `static`
  - returns `void` and takes a `String[]` argument as parameter
- A method named `main` doesn't have to be a Java application entry point

  - (but it's best to reserve this name for that purpose)

Furthermore,

- Instance fields/methods can only be accessed through an instance
- Static fields/methods can be accessed without an instance
- Static methods can get an instance of a class by one of the following ways:

  - creating a `new` instance
  - having it passed as an argument
  - accessing it through a `static` field of a class
  - accepting it as the return value of a `static` method of a class
  - catching it as a thrown `Throwable`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this piece of code will enlighten you:

```
public class Main {

    private String instanceField = "Joe";

    private void instanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("Instance name=" + instanceField);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // cannot change instance field without an instance
        instanceField = "Indy"; // compilation error

        // cannot call an instance method without an instance
        instanceMethod(); // compilation error

        // create an instance
        Main instance = new Main();

        // change instance field
        instance.instanceField = "Sydney";

        // call instance method
        instance.instanceMethod();  
    }
}
```

So you cannot access instance members without an instance. Within the context of a static method you don't have a reference to an instance unless you receive or create one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

A static method is called on a class instance and not to an object of a class. This means, that a static method is not able to access instance variables, because they are only instantiated in an object.

If you want to access an instance variable with a static method, you have to declare that variable as static.

```
public class Test {
    private static int value = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        value++;
    }
}
```

But to be honest, it's not the best idea to write everything in static methods. It's better to use the main method to instantiate new objects.

Answer (score 3):

To access non-static fields (instance variables) you need to have an instance.
Inside a non-static method, `this` is used as *default* instance:

```
class AnyClass  {

    private String nonStaticField = "Non static";

    void nonStaticMethod() {
        this.nonStaticField = "a text";  // accessing field of this
        nonStaticField = "a text";       // same as before
    }
}
```

---

Inside a static method there is no `this` to use as *default* instance, but you can<sup>**1**</sup> still access instance variables if you provide the instance:

```
class AnyClass {

    private String nonStaticField = "Non static";

    static void staticMethod() {
        AnyClass example = new AnyClass();
        example.nonStaticField = "new value for non-static field";
    }
}
```

**1** - the field must also be *accessible* by Java's *access control* (declared `public` or in the same class ...)

Answer (score 2):

One important thing is that unless u create an instance of an class the instance variables don't exist practically it means JVM doesn't that there os an variable like int i unless u create an instance for that class. so, using an instance variable in a static method is an compilation error.

```
class A{
    int i;
    static int j;
    static int b(){
        i=10; // cannot be found 
        A a= new A();
        a.i=10;//can be found in a's instance
    }
}
```

But, we can use instance variables in instance methods because, instance methods are only called when object created so there is no problem in using instance variables inside it.

Hope ur clear about these things!

Answer (score 0):

Yes static method cannot call non-static methods or variables of the class directly.

**EDIT** : One can create any local variables.

Comment: then how can we use non static variables in main method?

Comment: I think you need to show an example of what you think 'using a non-static variable in main' actually means.  I think you might be confused as to what a (non)static variable is.

Answer (score 0):

The static method can't access non-static variables outsides because you can use static method without class initialization, but it doesn't work for non-static outside variable. But you can define and use non-static variable in the static method.